# yii cadvancedarbehavior not saving object

Tags: yii

I am trying to use CAdvancedARBehavior to attach a image to a post , the MANY_MANY relationship works but when I try to save it as a object

`"Object of class Image could not be converted to int"`

```
$image->save();
$this->images = $image;
```

the same code partially works if I do

```
$image->save();
$this->images = $image->id;
```

however it will only save one image, if I try to add a new image it replaces the old in the join table, so the relationship only ever has one image at a time per post.

Comment: please post code of the model and class Image

Answer (score 0):

If you need more images that needs to be an array:

```
$image->save();
// add to image current list
$this->images[] = $image;
```

Comment: yeah I tried that already and I tried it by just adding $image->id, as well. Both error out. It seems like the logical answer doesn't it?

    Indirect modification of overloaded property Listing::$images has no effect